# Run ASP.NET Core 6 MVC app with attribute route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC application and when I run my app, I get a http 404 error:

[image]

Index action method:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/User/Dashboard")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {//mycodeishere}
}
```

The code in the `startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else 
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Error/{0}");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers(); // This maps all controller actions with attribute routing
        });

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
}
```

I keep the attribute route and redirect direct to `/client/dashboard` when I run the app

Comment: Hows your controller directory structure? Could you please share that one as well? currently, your route has been assigned to home page index? Do you have any action with Dashboard name?

Comment: Have you tried adding /User/Dashboard to the url in the browser? You might have to rename HomeController to UserController as I believe its convention based.

Comment: In your code, you've set the route to `[Route("/User/Dashboard")]`. This means that you should access it as `http://yourdomain/User/Dashboard`, not `http://yourdomain/client/dashboard`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: what you have is an mvc project and the default routing would make the home page as `localhost:port/home/index`, but you add a `[Route]` attribute on your `/home/index` method, which making your app doesn't have a method for `home/index` so you get 404

Answer (score 1):

When you are applying the `[Route("/User/Dashboard")]` attribute-route to the `Index` action method you actually avoid the `"default"` conventional route for the `Index`:

```cs
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

It's because the routes defined by the `Route` attributes have more privilege. Therefore, if want to hit the `\Home\Index` when entering the `localhost:44351` your should declare the default route like below:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet] // might be commented: it's default option
    [Route("")]
    [Route("/User/Dashboard")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
    {
    ....
    }
```

---

For an additional information see: [Routing to controller actions in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#set-up-conventional-route)

Pay attentions on the following sentences in the documentation:

> Actions are either conventionally-routed **or** attribute-routed. **Placing a route on the controller or action makes it attribute-routed**. See
> Mixed routing for more information.